# PostgreSQL create a schema under a different database using a script

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, schema, relational-database

So what I want to do here is to run a script while connected to a database I already had using pgAdmin3. The script contains a create role, tablespace, database and a create schema and several tables under that schema.

The problem here is that when I run the script it creates the new role, tablespace and database correctly. It also creates the schema and the tables correctly but with a problem, the schema is created under the database, from which I ran the script, instead of the newly created database. The script is more or less like this.

```
CREATE ROLE "new_role" ... ;

CREATE TABLESPACE "new_space"
  OWNER "new_role"
  LOCATION '/home/...';


CREATE DATABASE "new_db"
    WITH OWNER = "new_role"
            TABLESPACE = "new_space";

CREATE SCHEMA "schema" AUTHORIZATION "new_role" ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "schema"."new_table"( 

...  
) TABLESPACE "new_space";...

...
```

I already saw a solution with a `\connect foo;` but that is not what I wanted, I wanted it to somehow connect within the script without running things separately and running `\connect foo` in the terminal.

Can anyone tell me if there is anyway to do this and help me come out with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [*psql*](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) and split it up into two scripts . You can save the scripts in `.sql` files, and then run *psql* to connect to the DB you want to run each script against all on the same command line (with `&&` in between each command). The two *psql* commands could be combined into one *bash* script so it's only one command that you need to run.

Something like this, if the script were named `foo.sql`:

`psql -X -h <host> -U <user> -p <port> -f foo.sql <db_name>`

The first script could have the `create role`, `create tablespace` and `create database` commands, connecting to the `postgres` db or a *template* DB, and the second script could have the rest of the commands.

You could also use `createdb` from the *bash* script instead of `CREATE DATABASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Using pgAdminIV:
1- right click on default database "postgres"
2- select create database, give a name f.e. "newdatabase"
3- click on "newdatabase" (to establish connection)
4- open the query tool
5- import, write or paste your code
6- run your code f.e.: CREATE SCHEMA newschema;

It works for me...